# distribute library for iphone development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have created a project in xcode which creates a ".a" file. fine, this works! but now I want to give this .a file to another company, who have to develop with this classes. when I'm create a new project and add the .a file in the new project, no files could be found. for example: when I link to the "XRActionView.h" file or so (which is part of the .a file). I only want to deliver one file and no sources! is this possible?

thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A library only contains compiled binary, not the header files. In order for your client to use the library, you need to ship the header .h files as well.

Comment: yeh I know, but is there a possibility to distribute in one file?

Comment: No. You might put all your header files into one big .h file and ship two files only.

Comment: Not entirely sure what the OP meant by `deliver one file`, but you could also package the library as a zip file containing the .a file plus a directory containing the headers.